# How to know if an argument was passed to a (default arg) function of a generic class?

Tags: flutter, dart

If it was a normal function, I would do this.

```
void test([dynamic arg=_noArgs])
{
  if(arg==_noArg); // No argument was passed
  else if(arg==null); // null was explicitly passed
  else {} // handle the arg
}

const _noArgs = const Object(); // basically just create an instance of that type
```

But how can I achieve the same, for a function that belongs to a generic class and expects a parameter of that passed type?

```
void test([/*covariant*/ T arg=[...]])
{
  //[...];
}
```

Note: The default arg of a function has to be a constant.

Workaround for now:

```
void test([/*covariant*/ T arg=[...]])
{
  if(arg==null); // Argument was not passed (assumed)
  else{} // Handle the arg
}

void testNull()
{
  // Do whatever was supposed to be done if null was explicitly passed
}
```

Is there any better way to do it directly with the same function? (Sorry, I am too much into Dart's syntactic brevity)